# Trying to validate data and no rows are being found equal

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview, datatable, rows

I'm currently checking to see if datarows are equal to validate data. The rows contain columns are that are assigned different value types that could be datetimes, int, or escaped strings. Rows that do not have a match are highlighted in red. So far, I haven't been able to get my program to display any matching rows. I have tried using the DataRowComparer to do this for me but that gave me the same issue.

```
if(data.ColumnCount != dtSched.Columns.Count){
    MessageBox.Show("Unequal number of columns");
}
else
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow cRow in data.Rows){
        bool match = false;

        foreach(sRow in dtSched.Rows){
            DataRow temp;
            temp = ((DataRowView)cRow.DataBoundItem).Row;
            bool same = true;

            for(int i = 0; i < cRow.Cells.Count; i++){
                if(!temp[i].ToString().Equals(sRow[i].ToString())) same = false;
            }

            if(same == true) match = true;
        }
        if(match == false) cRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

thanks for the help. It is much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried outputting the comparable values to the debug window? they might not be as equal as you're expecting.

Comment: I can't see why they never match. But you don't break in your for loop that checks the cells, so only the value for the last cell in the row is really checked.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the breaks were definitely an issue but I assume the data i was comparing were of the same type when in reality they weren't. So I corrected both and it runs fine now